# How can see the SQL statements that SPARK sends to my database?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, vertica, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark cluster and a vertica database. I use

```
spark.read.jdbc( # etc
```

to load Spark dataframes into the cluster. When I do a certain groupby function

```
df2 = df.groupby('factor').agg(F.stddev('sum(PnL)'))
df2.show()
```

I then get a vertica syntax exception

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "Window"
    at com.vertica.util.ServerErrorData.buildException(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.io.ProtocolStream.readExpectedMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepareImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.jdbc4.S4PreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.VerticaJdbc4PreparedStatementImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.VJDBCObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1.<init>(JDBCRDD.scala:400)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.vertica.support.exceptions.SyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "Window"
    ... 27 more
```

What I want to know is, what exactly did spark try to execute against the vertica database? Is there a trace config I can set somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the [`query_requests`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/MONITOR/QUERY_REQUESTS.htm) system table to see what SQL has been run against your database. You can filter on `user_name` and `start_timestamp` to try and help find the query.

Typically when you control the SQL, you would want to add in a [label](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Profiling/HowToLabelQueriesForProfiling.htm).  But in this case you'll have to search for it.

Also be aware that the retention period of this is governed by the data collector settings.

Comment: This is super useful - thanks! However, just to note for others, this is a query in vertica, not spark.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Spark web UI you can check the behavior and performance of your Spark application. It can also show you the SQL's in SQL tab for web UI. You can also explore the Resource Manager log for more details.

```
Spark web UI at http://<host ip>:4040.
```

You can access the SQL tab under /SQL URL, e.g. http://:4040/SQL/.

Comment: For more details refer : https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-webui-sql.html

Comment: I think you are confusing SQL executions done of spark dataframes and the SQL statements that SPARK is making on my source (external) database. I am after that latter.

Comment: I think Spark WholeStageCodegen can give some details about the code generated by spark which will be executed on database.                                                                                                  Sparkcode.explain(true) -- will give the execution plan                                            ------------------------------------------------------------------                                                import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.debug._                                                                     df2.debugCodegen -- will give the generated code.

Comment: using .explain() was useful, but it doesn't specifically show what it will run against the database. Tracing it (see below) on the database side was much clearer.